# Show & Hide Div on data-id using Slick Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, slick.js

I have created a Slick Slider using UL & LI, below is the code:

```
 <ul class="slider">
     <li data-index="1">1</li>
     <li data-index="2">2</li>
     <li data-index="3">3</li>
     <li data-index="4">4</li>
     <li data-index="5">5</li>
  </ul>
```

The design looks likes [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylnJi.png)

Below is the section after ul li:

```
<section class="contentYear" data-id="1"></section>
<section class="contentYear" data-id="2"></section>
```

My requirement is that when slick slider is changed to 2, the contentYear with data-id=2 should be displayed.

I have written below code, but NO success

```
  $('.slider').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide){  
        $('.contentYear').hide();
        $('.contentYear[data-id=' + (currentSlide + 1) + ']').show();
    });
```

Can anyone help with this? I prefer to use slick slider, if no can suggest something where I can get this done.

Comment: I was trying
if($('div').hasClass('slick-active')){
            console.log($(this).parent().find('li').attr('data-index');
        }
But it returns undefined

Comment: Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/sutnx8b1/) working code.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the value of currentSlide supposed to come from?
You have to somehow remember which number is showing in the slider.

A quick and dirty solution would be having a global variable in which you store the currentSlide Value.